# Weird results on iphone from jquery get

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, mysql, ajax

So I'm getting weird results on my iPhone4 from a jquery "get" code I've written. 
Basically, the code suggests words from a mysql database generated with php.

The code is at `http://111.89.128.27/smt/?nsd`

In any desktop browser, the code works just fine. 
In the first input form, please key-in "p" and it will return(alert) this:

```
<li class="data-row"><a class="data-click" href="#PC無償貸与制度">PC無償貸与制度</a></li>
<li class="data-row"><a class="data-click" href="#理学療法士">理学療法士</a>
</li>
<li class="data-row"><a class="data-click" href="#DTPオペレーター・DTPクリエイター">DTPオペレーター・DTPクリエイター</a></li>
<li class="data-row"><a class="data-click" href="#マイクロソフト・オフィススペシャリスト(MOS)">マイクロソフト・オフィススペシャリスト(MOS)</a></li>
<li class="data-row"><a class="data-click" href="#ＪＡＰＡＮサッカーカレッジ">ＪＡＰＡＮサッカーカレッジ</a></li>
```

The same result appears in my iPad2 tablet which is good.

However, in my iPhone4, the results are displaying the current code.

Has anyone encountered this issue and know a fix? 
I appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: chinese characters AND an IP address URL, yeah, I'm going to visit that link...

Comment: @RockyTriton 

#1 it's japanese characters 
#2 it's my dev server. thanks for your huge help though.